# keepSynced in Unity Firebase SDK

Tags: c#, firebase, unity-game-engine, firebase-realtime-database

I'm using Firebase Unity SDK - offline mode with `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.SetPersistenceEnabled(true)`
`

and I'm trying yo keep a certain reference synced with this code `keepSynced(true)`

this is the code `FirebaseDatabase.DefaultInstance.GetReference("Node").keepSynced(true);`

yet Unity shows

`'DatabaseReference' does not contain a definition for 'keepSynced' and no accessible extension method 'keepSynced' accepting a first argument of type 'DatabaseReference' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

What is the proper way to make it work ?

Comment: Can you add the line that you are defining DatabaseReference?

Comment: @user1579019 I added it in the question!

Comment: Use it like this : DatabaseReference r = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("chat/roomid"); r.keepSynced(true);